# Symfony2 : addListener without using EventSubscriber class

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I have a manager and inside a method.
Inside this method, I want to add a listener connect to Doctrine and use this :

```
$dispatcher = $this->container->get("event_dispatcher");
$dispatcher->addListener(Events::onFlush, function (Event $event) {
    var_dump('test');die;
});
```

But in this case nothing append.
Do you have a solution to accomplish this ? I read a lot of time documentation about listener but I don't understand why didn't work :/
(and I don't want to use EventSubscriber class)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good, you have to use the doctrine event dispatcher and not the Symfony one.

```
$doctrineEventManager = $this->em->getEventManager();
$doctrineEventManager->addEventListener(Events::onFlush, New YourEventListenerClass()});;
```

Comment: It was one of my try but doing this I have this error : "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Closure::onFlush()" :/

Comment: yes of course the Closure should be well written, give a look to the doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush. ```public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)```

Comment: Your are true but in this case it's like doing a "EventSubscriber class" and it was what I want avoid :(